# visual studio code looks blurry

Tags: visual-studio-code, blurry

Here are my visual studio code version details:

```
Version: 1.26.1
Commit: 493869ee8e8a846b0855873886fc79d480d342de
Date: 2018-08-16T18:38:57.434Z
Electron: 2.0.5
Chrome: 61.0.3163.100
Node.js: 8.9.3
V8: 6.1.534.41
Architecture: x64
```

Once I updated to this version, the entire app started looking blurry. It was fine before the update and has been looking fine on this windows 10 machine.

I got other Microsoft Apps - Office Word, Excel and the rest, and they all fine. Visual Studio (regular) looks fine. Its this software and only since the latest update to 1.26.1

[image: visual studio code looks blurry]

Note: There is one other software which always had a blurry appearance, and that is Postman. I assumed that it is a Postman issue so never got around to fixing it or try fixing. adding this here if there is a connection but the question is primarily about Code, and how I could fix the appearance problem.

Update 1 :

So, I opened Postman and that also has stopped being blurry. So, looks like the blame does fall on AMD Radeon rather than MS or Postman developers.

Comment: Is you try to uninstall it and re-install it ?

Comment: See this [GitHub Post](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1334)

Comment: There are some extensions I've read that can cause this. Maybe you should check your extensions.

Comment: folks, the video card comment from yashu has done the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First of all please accept my apologize for not responding so soon, I
>   am afraid I can't provide you with a feedback because the issue were
>   my AMD Radeon Graphics Drivers, after an Update was released the issue
>   was gone. Thanks for your hard work!
>
> *Read this [comment on github](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1334#issuecomment-224201111)*.

It is possible that there is some kind of an issue with your Graphic card, try updating your Graphic card drivers.

Comment: I looked at that thread. the thing is, the issue only happened immediately after the update. All other apps (which used to have scaling issues identical to the above, such as Microsoft Word seems to be working fine) are running just fine. 

Still, I will check the drivers and post an update here.

Comment: Update. Right then, so the driver update did fix the problem. Still, I dont know why a basic editor needs a graphics card driver update just to look proper. Anyway, back to work then.

Answer (score 91):

1. NVIDIA Control Panel
2. Manage 3D settings
3. Program Settings
4. Select VS Code from dropdown or add it if it's not there
5. Set "Antialiasing - FXAA" to OFF

> https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/9szgkp/visual_studio_code_blurry/

Comment: Make sure also to restart VSCode.

Comment: Also worth considering disabling at global level, then enabling per application you want it enabled on

Answer (score 20):

I know this is late but just in case it didn't work for someone, here is another solution:

Right click on VsCode and go to properties.
Copy this command

```
--disable-gpu --enable-use-zoom-for-dsf
```

and append it to the target path n the shortcut properties dialog.
Click apply and the reopen VScode.

Here is the article that I am referencing  https://medium.com/kasun-kodagoda/fix-text-becomes-blurry-when-vs-code-application-loses-focus-issue-on-windows-d95697b2f927

Comment: Fixed my issues, Thanks !

Comment: This is the real solution, not related to my graphics card drivers. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Try turning Off Anti-Aliasing in your Graphics Settings.Since it Over Renders the Text.

Answer (score 6):

Go into your settings and type "rendering" you should see "Terminal > Integrated: Gpu Acceleration" if you turn if off it should fix the problem.

Comment: That worked like a charm but this issue happens in some other apps too.

Answer (score 4):

Go to settings.json and add - "terminal.integrated.gpuAcceleration": "off"

Answer (score 3):

I tried updating my drivers as suggested by Yashu Mittal without any luck. After some tinkering I realized that it is because I had set Anti-Aliasing to something other than "application control" in my graphics card settings.

Answer (score 3):

I have a problem every now and then where just the terminal gets blurry. I simply zoom in and zoom out ("⌘=", "⌘-") and it fixes them problem.

Answer (score 3):

For AMD:

1. Open AMD Radeon Software Panel
2. Go to Settings > Graphics Tab > Advance Settings > Morphological Anti-Aliasing (x) disable this option.

[IMAGE LINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6CJ4.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30301025)

Comment: edited, no problem. i don't have reference i just found my issue to share with others :>

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I tried almost everything and was trying to report this issue on GitHub cause nothing worked. Then I found your answer and it worked perfectly once I relaunched the Visual Studio Code software.

Answer (score 0):

For those who have a similar issue but in Visual Studio IDE (currently, I am using 2019 edition).

Go to "Tools -> Options -> General", and turn on "Optimize rendering for screens with different pixel densities"

[link to the settings image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLhyF.png)

Answer (score 0):

After some research to this issue i found something that worked for me.

1. I tried the methods that most were listing which is > Display settings > manage 3D settings > Program settings > turning off the noted solutions. This did not help and was not showing any difference overall. It got so bad i couldn't even tell what program i had open. [See here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilSJ7.jpg)

What worked for me was >Display Settings> manage 3D settings > Restore to default.
This worked immediately. i did not go into the Program settings. This change would be global.
Most likely more apps are sharing the same problem not just one Word, VS Code, Chrome, Etc..

Comment: I believe this only solves the problem if the default settings are correction your machine.